# When received money in Phonepe, Gpay, Paytm then send notification data to streamelements using streamelements API using shell script

Tags: streaming, google-pay, steam-web-api, paytm, phonepe

I want to create script when received money in Phonepe, Gpay, Paytm then send notification data to streamelements using streamelements API Please guide me how to do this. I want to use API of UPI like Phonepe, Gpay, Paytm.

https://dev.streamelements.com/docs/api-docs/7e632a4cecfe1-channel

I am trying streamelements APIs and its working fine.

https://dev.streamelements.com/docs/api-docs/7e632a4cecfe1-channel

I do not any knowledge about UPI API please guide me. It is best if script written in bash, shell script